# How to set column and row of elements in GridLayout in Android

Tags: android, imagebutton, grid-layout

I have a GridLayout containing several ImageButtons such as

```
   <ImageButton
       android:id="@+id/btnColor00"
       android:layout_column="0"
       android:layout_row="0" />
```

The layout shows ImageButtons correctly but I want to implement it programmatically to create a GridLayout of ImageButtons dynamically.

I programmed code below but what I don't know yet is how to set android:layout_column, android:layout_row programmatically.

```
    ibs = new ImageButton[42];

    for (int i=0; i<42;i++) {
        ibs[i] = new ImageButton(getContext());
        LayoutParams params = ibs[i].getLayoutParams();
        params.height = 40;
        params.width = 40;

        ibs[i].setLayoutParams(params);
    }
```

I searched LayoutParams and ImageButton's methods but couldn't find any similiar command.
Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are different `LayoutParams` classes for different layouts.  You need to use GridLayout.LayoutParams.

```
GridLayout.LayoutParams params = (GridLayout.LayoutParams)ibs[i].getLayoutParams();
```

Comment: I have the same problem, I don't understand how to set layout_column and layout_row in the params object. Could you help me?